# How to iter a StructChunked in polars?

Tags: json, python-polars, rust-polars, pyo3

I'm working on an extension for the Python Polars library to convert a Struct into JSON. The goal is to use the fields of the struct as the keys and their corresponding values as the JSON values. However, I'm finding it much harder to handle StructChunked than python's pl.struct.

Does anyone have any suggestions or code examples on how to approach this? Any insights or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my uncompilable code:

```
use polars::prelude::*;
use pyo3_polars::derive::polars_expr;
use serde_json::*;

#[polars_expr(output_type=Utf8)]
fn to_json(inputs: &[Series]) -> PolarsResult<Series> {
    let ca: &StructChunked = inputs[0].struct_()?;
    let out: Utf8Chunked = ca
        .into_iter()
        .map(|row| serde_json::to_string(row).unwrap())
        .collect();
    Ok(out.into_series())
}
```

Comment: [`struct.json_encode`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.struct.json_encode.html#polars.Expr.struct.json_encode) was recently added to Polars. https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/pull/12583

Comment: I think it's like if you iterate over a dataframe: `for s in df` you get a Series for each column. A StructChunked/Array contains a separate "Array" for each field, they are not actually stored as "rows" (this is cheap/efficient). You would need to "zip" each inner "Array" to process them as "rows".